# remove characters including | but only up to (not including) >

Tags: regex, sed

in the pattern

```
<Blast>uce-506_drosophila_albomicans |uce506</BlastOutput_query-def>
```

I'm trying to remove |* up to (but not including) <

I tried (but doesn't achieve it)

```
sed 's/^|[^<]*//g' dataset2.fasta.xml >dataset2_2.fasta.xml
```

Comment: What is the expected output for given sample?

Comment: You need  `\|[^<>]*(?=<)`

Answer (score 0):

Single caret `^` means "*start at the beginning of the line*." Remove it:

```
sed 's/|[^<]*//g'
```